# How to create a Windows Compatible Encrypted disk image?

Tags: applescript, command-line, disk-utility, encryption, compatibility

I need to send a file over Email securely.  My idea was to use a Disk Image containing the file.  Unfortunately, the person who I am sending the file to has a PC running Windows 10.

I need a way (most likely through the command line) to create an **Encrypted** Disk Image from a folder that is both **read and write** compatible on both **Mac's and PC**.

Even better would be an Apple Script Droplet that would take a **file** (not a folder) create a folder and then create an **Encrypted** Disk Image from that folder that is both **read and write** compatible on both **Mac's and PC** and then remove the original file and folder.

**Note:**  Shell scripts are fine for the Apple Script Droplet.

I have tried creating an encrypted .cdr image and then changing the extension to .iso.  Worked on Mac, but "Error...Corrupted" on PC.

I have also tried
`hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o [filename].iso [encryptedfile].cdr`
It worked but it was not encrypted.

Comment: Zip file with a password is a possible solution. Worked for me sending out exam templates 3 weeks before the exam...

Comment: @SolarMike Not a bad idea, but I was thinking that a Disk Image encryption was more secure then a Zip file encryption. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don’t have that answer, but one student out of 125 told me he had cracked the password - kept telling me for 2 weeks ... so, start of the exam I asked him in front of all the other students what the password was .... He had to admit that he didn’t know :) So I said lucky I know it .... :) Don’t they say most stuff is crackable - it depends on the resources you can throw at it...

Comment: @SolarMike Smart teacher :).  Wish we had some of those at my school‍♂️....From my 5min research it appears the only way to crack is brute force. So I may end up using that as our solution. Thanks. Will keep this question open as it is still useful.

Comment: I used passwords like “dumbledore” well it was topical at the time - I know no real words etc...

Comment: @SolarMike https://security.stackexchange.com/q/186128/163099